# Contact list on iPhone without using contact picker

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

I am working on an iPhone application. Can someone tell me how can I display all my contact list in my mobile without using Contactpicker? How do I display all my contact list in iPhone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to fetch the addressbook contacts and show it into uitableview, see apple addressbook programming guid here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

Comment: hi,Can i some one tell me code to get all the contacts list in my mobile without using Contactpicker. I need to get name and mobile number.

Comment: ask some question or tell any place

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not understandable. I need to get all the contacts in a tableview. I am displaying a tableview. I just need to display all the contacts in my mobile. How can i achive it. Any sample code will be of great use to me. Can u guide me.

Comment: yeah i have understood it and i m asking where i do give you the code. it will not be complete in comment

Comment: If you can use www.pastebin.com and in that copy and paste the code and upload it. You will be left with a URL in address bar. Send the URL to me. I can view the code.