# How to get all the address book contacts from iphone

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am new to iphone. I am stuck in my project in the step of getting all the address book contacts mainly(name and email) which are placed in iphone device into my table view which is created in my project. How can I do it?

Comment: duplicate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558543/iphone-address-book-sample-code the official doc is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/ https://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Functions/index.html

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableArray* contactsArray = [NSMutableArray new];

// open the default address book. 
ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();

if (!m_addressbook) 
{
    NSLog(@"opening address book");
}
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);
for (int i=0;i < nPeople;i++) 
{ 
    NSMutableDictionary* tempContactDic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);
    CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
    firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    [tempContactDic setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    //fetch email id
    NSString *strEmail;
    ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    CFStringRef tempEmailref = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, 0);
    strEmail = (__bridge  NSString *)tempEmailref;

    [tempContactDic setValue:strEmail forKey:@"email"];

     [contactsArray addObject:tempContactDic];

}
```

all contacts Data saved in Contacts Array. Then you can use this array according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

use addressbook api to do this. see my answer here

[Contact list on iPhone without using contact picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496589/contact-list-on-iphone-without-using-contact-picker/10496623#10496623)

and for more details get the apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    NSMutableArray* contactsArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    if (!m_addressbook)
    {
        NSLog(@"opening address book");
    }
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);
    for (int i=0;i < nPeople;i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* tempContactDic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);
        NSLog(@"tempContactDic ios a ==%@",tempContactDic);
       CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
        firstName = (__bridge CFStringRef)((__bridge UILabel *)(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)));
        lastName  = (__bridge CFStringRef)((__bridge UILabel *)(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty)));
      //  [tempContactDic setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
        //fetch email id
        NSString *strEmail;
        ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        CFStringRef tempEmailref = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, 0);
        strEmail = (__bridge  NSString *)tempEmailref;

        [tempContactDic setValue:strEmail forKey:@"email"];

        [contactsArray addObject:tempContactDic];

    }

}
-(IBAction)getcontactlist:(id)sender{

         [self getContact];
}

-(IBAction)getContact {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    firstName.text = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    lastName.text = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    number.text = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
    return NO;
}
```

This code is working fine for me...